# Apply a grunge texture across an array

Tags: modifiers

I am experimenting with creating a wooden plank array. The texture uses the Generated option in the texture coordinate node for texture variation on the array objects. The modifier stack includes subsurf and displace modifiers to create some mesh variations for each array object.

I am wondering: is it possible to apply a grunge texture across the entire array? For example, a drip stain from top to bottom if the array was used for a wall. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: The array]

[image: Node]

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out with the following node setup.

[image]

The grunge texture is applied via the object option in the texture Coordinates node.

Comment: An alternative is to use another object's coordinates (or an empty) to control the texture mapping.